# Maliit onscreen keyboard installed on MSI Windpad 110w tablet in Saucy,but will not open

Tags: 13.10, touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard

I downloaded Maliit keyboard via 'apt-get' and the install went ahead without a hitch,however the joy ends there as I am at a loss as to why it will not work.Maliit ran perfectly on this tablet in 12.04 LTS. Could someone please provide me with definitive instructions on how to properly  download and configure Maliit for 13.10.
Thank-you in advance.

Comment: I double checked the repos for correctness,and installed maliit overtop of previous download,all packages were installed correctly. still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

To install maliit-keyboard just follow these instructions.

Check the universe repository is enabled.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Ensure that universe is included.

you can do it GUI Open ubuntu software center then click on Edit -> Software Sources and then check on the universe item.

[image]

After any changes you should run this command to update your system.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You can now install the package like this.

```
sudo apt-get install maliit-keyboard
```

Which will install maliit-keyboard and any other packages on which it depends.

[source](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/saucy/universe/m/maliit-keyboard/install.html) and [more information](https://wiki.maliit.org/Main_Page)